# Array of NSLocalizedStrings

Tags: ios, arrays, localization, nslocalizedstring

I'm trying to programmatically localize my project, since base internationalization isn't automatically picking up my menu items on my storyboard. I'd like to localize the strings in an array. The specific problem I'm having is this code:

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad

   {

_menuItems = @[@"title",
                    @"item1",
                    @"item2",
                    @"item3",
                    @"item4",                   
                   ];

}
```

I've tried declaring

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"title")];
```

for each one, but that does't compile so I'm sure that's not right. I'd be grateful for anyone's help to point me in the right direction.

Comment: For starters, that's the wrong format of the macro (including the missing quote to terminate the string).  There's a second parameter to the macro which is a hint to the translator and provides some context for them.  Take a look at this article for an explanation of how NSLocalizedString works: http://nshipster.com/nslocalizedstring/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    _menuItems = @[ NSLocalizedString(@"title1", @"the title"),
                    NSLocalizedString(@"item1", @"the first item"),
                    NSLocalizedString(@"item2", @"the second item"),
                    NSLocalizedString(@"item3", @"the third item"),
                    NSLocalizedString(@"item4", @"the fourth item")
                   ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I see now how that link related to the answer. I didn't realize I was on the right track, but formatting it wrong. I understand better, I appreciate your time.